# Feature mapping using multi-variable polynomial

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, mapping, octave, linear-regression

Consider we have a data-matrix of [image]  data points [image] and we are interested to map those data points into a higher dimensional feature space. We can do this by using d-degree polynomials. Thus for a sequence of [image] data points the new data-matrix is

[image]

I have studied a relevant script (*Andrew Ng. online course*) that make such a transform for 2-dimensional data points to a higher feature space. However, I could not figure out a way to generalize in arbitrary higher dimensional samples, [image]. Here is the code:

```
d = 6;
m = size(D,1); 
new = ones(m);
for k = 1:d
    for l = 0:k
        new(:, end+1) = (x1.^(k-l)).*(x2.^l);
    end
end
```

Can we vectorize this code? Also given a data-matrix [image] could you please suggest a way on how we can transform data points of arbitrary dimension to a higher one using a d-dimensional polynomial?

**PS: A generalization of d-dimensional data points would be very helpful.**

Comment: where is j coming from

Comment: Here is the relevant provided mapFeature code provided in coursera : https://github.com/jcgillespie/Coursera-Machine-Learning/blob/master/ex2/mapFeature.m

Comment: There is a significant amount of literature on this sort of problem in the digital predistortion field.  If we treat the D dimensions as delays in a time series then nonlinear kernels like the Volterra series or the Hammerstein series can be used to create nonlinear features.  There is also work on othogonal nonlinear polynomials, which have the added advantage of making the "data matrix" less singular (I.e. more invertible).  This is useful if you're trying to do a least squares fit to the polynomial features.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution can handle `k` variables and generate all the terms of a degree `d` polynomial where `k` and `d` are non-negative integers. Most of the code length is due to the combinatoric complexity of generating all the terms of a degree `d` polynomial in `k` variables.

It takes an `n_obs` by `k` data matrix `X` where `n_obs` is the number of observations and `k` is the number of variables.

#### Helper function

This function generates all possible rows such that every entry is a non-negative integer and the row sums to a positive integer:

```
the row [0, 1, 3, 0, 1]  corresponds to (x1^0)*(x1^1)*(x2^3)*(x4^0)*(x5^1)
```

The function (which almost certainly could be written more efficiently) is:

```
function result = mg_sums(n_numbers, d)
if(n_numbers<=1)
    result = d;
else
    result = zeros(0, n_numbers);    
    for(i = d:-1:0)
        rc = mg_sums(n_numbers - 1, d - i);
        result = [result; i * ones(size(rc,1), 1), rc];
    end    
end
```

#### Initialization code

```
n_obs  = 1000;  % number observations
n_vars = 3;     % number of variables
max_degree  = 4;     % order of polynomial

X = rand(n_obs, n_vars);  % generate random, strictly positive data

stacked = zeros(0, n_vars); %this will collect all the coefficients...    
for(d = 1:max_degree)          % for degree 1 polynomial to degree 'order'
    stacked = [stacked; mg_sums(n_vars, d)];
end
```

#### Final Step: Method 1

```
newX = zeros(size(X,1), size(stacked,1));
for(i = 1:size(stacked,1))
    accumulator = ones(n_obs, 1);
    for(j = 1:n_vars)
        accumulator = accumulator .* X(:,j).^stacked(i,j);
    end
    newX(:,i) = accumulator;
end
```

Use *either* method 1 or method 2.

#### Final Step: Method 2 (requires all data in data matrix X is *strictly positive* (The problem is that if you have 0 elements, the `-inf` doesn't propagate properly when you call the matrix algebra routines.)

```
newX = real(exp(log(X) * stacked'));  % multiplying log of data matrix by the    
                                % matrix of all possible exponent combinations
                                % effectively raises terms to powers and multiplies them!
```

### Example Run

```
X = [2, 3, 5];
max_degree = 3;
```

The stacked matrix and the polynomial term it represents are:

```
 1     0     0        x1           2
 0     1     0        x2           3 
 0     0     1        x3           5
 2     0     0        x1.^2        4
 1     1     0        x1.*x2       6
 1     0     1        x1.*x3       10
 0     2     0        x2.^2        9
 0     1     1        x2.*x3       15
 0     0     2        x3.^2        25
 3     0     0        x1.^3        8
 2     1     0        x1.^2.*x2    12
 2     0     1        x1.^2.*x3    20
 1     2     0        x1.*x2.^2    18
 1     1     1        x1.*x2.*x3   30
 1     0     2        x1.*x3.^2    50
 0     3     0        x2.^3        27
 0     2     1        x2.^2.*x3    45
 0     1     2        x2.*x3.^2    75
 0     0     3        x3.^3        125
```

If data matrix `X` is `[2, 3, 5]` this correctly generates:

```
newX = [2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 10, 9, 15, 25, 8, 12, 20, 18, 30, 50, 27, 45, 75, 125];
```

Where the 1st column is `x1`, 2nd is `x2`, 3rd is `x3`, 4th is `x1.^2`, 5th is `x1.*x2` etc...

Comment: Seems fine. I put this answer in a re-usable gist : https://gist.github.com/almathie/53f955bfeb14c45e2638

Comment: After more testing, this does not work : Try it with matrix :
A = [0 , 1, 2, 3 ; 10, 20, 30, 40] .
Order = 3

Comment: @almathie you're right, hmm, current version of code assumes all data in the data matrix is non-zero and positive...  Rats! I think I can't use my log trick :/